# Getting ValueError for checking stock price data

Tags: python, quantitative-finance

I am currently learning a bit abount machine learning funamdentals and I am having trouble implementing a regression model. I do not really understand how to solve it as I am still getting use to statistical analysis with python. I am recieving the ValueError:

```
Shape of passed values is (13, 1), indices imply (22, 1)
```

Here is the code in case this can help visualize what I am dealing with `

```
# sklearn for importing regression model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# pandas and numpy are used for data manipulation 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# matplotlib and seaborn are used for plotting graphs 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn 

# yfinance is used to fetch data 
import yfinance as yf

# get S&P500 ticker
stock_data = yf.download('SPY','2021-06-23','2022-11-23')

# Only keep close columns 
stock_data = stock_data[['Close']] 

# Drop rows with missing values 
stock_data = stock_data.dropna() 

# Plot the closing price 
stock_data.Close.plot(figsize=(10,5)) 
plt.ylabel("SPY Prices")
plt.show()

# 3-day and 9-day moving average
stock_data['S_3'] = stock_data['Close'].shift(1).rolling(window=3).mean() 
stock_data['S_9']= stock_data['Close'].shift(1).rolling(window=9).mean() 
stock_data= stock_data.dropna() 

# Explanatory Variables
X = stock_data[['S_3','S_9']] 
X.head()

# Dependent Variable
y = stock_data['Close']
y.head()

t=.8 
t = int(t*len(stock_data)) 

# Train dataset 
X_train = X[:t] 
y_train = y[:t]  

# Test dataset 
X_test = X[t:] 
y_test = y[t:]

linear = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)

predicted_price = linear.predict(X_test)  
predicted_price = pd.DataFrame(predicted_price, index=y_test.index, columns = ['price'])  
predicted_price.plot(figsize=(10,5))  
y_test.plot()  

plt.legend(['predicted_price','actual_price'])  
plt.ylabel("SPY Price")  
plt.show()
```

`

I tried to see if the issue was the data range. However, that did not work. I tried looking up the solution, but for some reason I could not find an example that would explain what the issue was.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error with the current code. For debugging help, please post the full error traceback, along with the actual code that produced the error.

Comment: I also tried running the code you supplied, and it ran fine. As said, do add the error that you're getting to your question. Is it possible that you're running only parts of the code? Or that you're inside of an interactive session where some variables have unexpected values? Try running that code from a clean python session, maybe that is your issue?

Comment: This is the line that causes ValueError for me:

predicted_price = pd.DataFrame(predicted_price, index=y_test.index, columns = ['price'])